# didSelectRowAt - performSegue indexPath.row to VCs with a different design

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have recently started Xcode and I following one example I did a 'didSelectRowAt' to go from my decided image to the View I want. That's good and all, but now I want to go to Different storyboards and not use my recycled View. I have been pounding this for a couple of days and I really can't seem to figure out how.

This is my VC.swift

```
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var categoryTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    categoryTable.dataSource = self
    categoryTable.delegate = self


}

    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProductsVC", sender: category)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: kitListIdentifier, sender: category)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let productsVC = segue.destination as? ProductsVC {
        let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
        barBtn.title = ""
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtn
        assert(sender as? Category != nil)
        productsVC.initProducts(category: sender as! Category)


    }

}
```

}

And this is my storyboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf8bR.png)

Aas you see I want to go to KitList based on the image position I choose from the first VC.
In this case, position 0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M1ke.png)

Could you give me some help?

Thanks

Comment: why are you doing 2 segues? you want to go to 2 controllers in the same time?

Comment: In `didSelectRowAt` read the indexPath.row and perform the target segue with the correct identifier. In prepareForSegue, just check the segue.identifier and do an if/else and manage them.

Comment: Just a tip, posts with external image links are often more harder to receive help on, you should embed the images in your post for better feedback.

Comment: @Lu, no I don't, although I know that is whats happening right now. I want to be able to choose which I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)    {
   let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
   if(indexPath.row == 0)
   {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: kitListIdentifier, sender: category)
   }
   else
   {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProductsVC", sender: category)
   }


}
```

Comment: going to try this thanks. Is this the recommended way though:? thanks

Comment: it worked, thats great... would a switch case be better? or same thing?

Comment: it's recommended by me =D , yes you can use switch

Comment: @XkOltn26 : It's important that if an answer worked for you, you accept it. That benefits developers around the globe. If someone would face a similar issue as you were, your question and this answer would help to fix the issue.